# SVG curve low quality (steps, edges) on MacOS Chrome

Tags: macos, svg, bezier, curve, smoothing

The example [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQrMm.png]

The SVG:

```html
<svg
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1"
  viewBox="0 0 900 2000"
  height="2000px"
  width="900px">

    <g transform="translate(300,50)">
    
      <-- The curve which looks with edges in MacOS Chrome -->
      <path d="M-120.83544557088219 1738.5018312545567 C -118.08223960250174 1670.3356213839381 -85.72445908423663 -7.022567888738819 -4.350971392762291 -6.5264570891434355 19.999547450916797 -6.377998964552493 62.00037168873135 -6.121931993756162 82 -6 90.9998327400709 -5.9451306028097255 90.99979315194402 5.938981787787313 82 6 62.000459662346636 6.135596027139307 19.999640336539393 6.420359783756897 4.350971392762291 6.5264570891434355 -77.02215835606484 7.078163424566491 -89.52618961315629 1672.1434954260517 -96.16455442911781 1739.4981687454433 -101.16314519095648 1749.8779851769993 -117.13209354719626 1748.8816476861125 -120.83544557088219 1738.5018312545567" fill="#786CB4" stroke="none" stroke-width="0"></path>
    </g>
      
</svg>
```

I have `shape-rendering`, but it do different thing.

How can one make curve smooth in MacOS Chrome?

Comment: This is not a macOs only issue it's a GPU one in Skia, I can repro on [Skia fiddle](https://fiddle.skia.org/c/a537d53b35f5769080beee0c53f96739). Feel free to [open an issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/skia/issues/entry?comment=Visit%20this%20link%20to%20see%20the%20issue%20on%20fiddle%3A%0A%0A%20https%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.skia.org%2Fc%2Fa537d53b35f5769080beee0c53f96739).

Comment: Also blocky on Chrome/Windows - so it's a Chrome bug

Comment: I did open https://bugs.chromium.org/p/skia/issues/detail?id=11886

Comment: Thanks so much for answers and the post editing!

Well, could you tell me, how can I disable the gpu as a temporary solution?

Comment: As a known bug with an issue filed, this can probably be closed on SO (as anyone who finds it here will be able to click through to kaiido's link, and hopefully in the near future, this bug gets fixed =)

Comment: **For your personal use** you can disable GPU rendering in Chrome by going to `chrome://settings/system` and unchecking the "Use hardware acceleration when available" tick. However there is no way (I know of) to force rendering on CPU to your users... @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans probably one could find a workaround though, maybe using other path commands to achieve a visually-similar path? (You're the specialist in curves)

Comment: I am, but not when it comes to poly-curve joins in specific engines. One workaround is to overlay circles at the appropriate radius on your joins to get something that at least looks similar to what it "should" look like, but I would certain defer to "waiting for the bug to get fixed in Skia and have Chrome (and FF? Last time I checked they also used Skia but it's been a few years) update eventually" in this case. The amount of pathing code required is really just not worth it compared to just waiting out the bug-fix for a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes, you're right. Some weeks or months I can wait. It is not a critical problem.